# How to return array of values from PostgreSQL function by INT id

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, function

I am trying to create a simple PostgreSQL function, where by using `INT` parameter I like to get array back. The example below will not work, but shall give idea of what I try to get back from a function. Thanks.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contact_countries_array(INT)
  RETURNS ANYARRAY AS '
  SELECT ARRAY[contacts_primarycountry, contacts_othercountry] FROM contacts WHERE contacts_id = $1'
  LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The data type of contacts_primarycountry and contacts_othercountry is integer. contacts_id is unique and integer.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35374093/edit) your question add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. I have no idea what you are trying to do

Comment: you are right, I forgot to describe wished data types

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the docs:

> It is permitted to have polymorphic arguments with a fixed return
>   type, but the converse is not.

As such, I think your attempt to return `anyarray` won't work.

Your fields look like text, so I think if you altered it to something like this, it would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contact_countries_array(INT)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
  select array[contacts_primarycountry::text, contacts_othercountry::text]
  FROM contacts WHERE contacts_id = $1
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This should compile, and it *might* work, but I'm honestly not sure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contact_countries_array(anyelement)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
  select array[contacts_primarycountry::text, contacts_othercountry::text]
  FROM contacts WHERE contacts_id = $1
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I think the datatypes would have to match perfectly for this to work, unless you did casting.

Comment: Yes to the first variant, assuming that `contacts.contacts_id` is defined `UNIQUE`. The polymorphic type in the second one is probably unwarranted as the data type of `contacts.contacts_id` should be known in advance anyway.

Comment: Thank you people. Based on @Hambone, I have tried it like this: 

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contact_countries_array(ANYELEMENT)
RETURNS ANYARRAY AS '
    SELECT ARRAY[contacts_primarycountry::int, contacts_othercountry::int] FROM contacts WHERE contacts_id = $1'
LANGUAGE SQL;`

and now it works. It returns like {55,81} as 2 possible countries of the contact, that I can compare now to list of countries with {55,81} && {55,82,101,12}, @Hambone, thank you much, @a_horse_with_no_name, @erwin_brandstetter

Comment: Doesn't it require a `return` inside function, for it to be a valid code?

Comment: @Eugene -- not when it's `LANGUAGE SQL`.  You're probably thinking pgplsql

Answer (score 10):

**Declaring Array, Looping, Adding items to Array, Returning Array with Postgres Function,**

You can declare `INTEGER` array instead of `TEXT` and avoid casting `(counter::TEXT)` as well as return type `TEXT[]`. *(Added those for reference.)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetNumbers"(maxNo INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT[] AS $nums$

DECLARE 
    counter INTEGER := 0;
    nums TEXT[] := ARRAY[]::TEXT[];

BEGIN
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN counter = maxNo;
        counter = counter + 1;
        nums = array_append(nums, counter::TEXT);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN nums;
END ;

$nums$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT "GetNumbers"(5); -- {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Comment: The script does not work.   Here is an updated version.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_numbers(maxNo INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT[] AS $$
DECLARE 
    counter INTEGER := 0;
    nums TEXT[] := ARRAY[]::TEXT[];

BEGIN
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN counter = maxNo;
        counter = counter + 1;
        nums = array_append(nums, counter::TEXT);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN nums;
END ;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: Thank you nick, I updated the function. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create `my_func()` which can return `VARCHAR[]` type as shown below. *You can replace `VARCHAR[]` with `TEXT[]`.:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VARCHAR[]
AS $$                          -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
SELECT ARRAY['John','David','Robert'];
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns an array as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
       my_func
---------------------
 {John,David,Robert}
(1 row)
```